# Filter SQL data connection in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

In InfoPath I retrieve a data from SQL view with 2000 records, to show a specific fields in the InfoPath form based on the current SharePoint site URL.

I face a performance issue to load all 2000 records when the form open.

I need to filter the data connection based on the current SharePoint site URL during configure SQL data connection in InfoPath. instead of retrieve 2000 record only retrieve a one filtered record!

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't set a filter during creating a SQL data connection in infopath.

you can only get the data then filter each field in your form with your criteria,
In your case I think there is a function in InfoPath called `SharePointURL()` that you can filter with it, meanwhile, it will require binding all the data on load.

but there is a workaround to get filtered data by

- Creating a web service that receives your data from your view.
- Create a Web Service data source.
- Set parameter for the Web Service function.
- Do the Web Service Call
- Set field values for each field from the web service data source.

You can check the detail steps with image at [InfoPath and Web Service data connection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jannemattila/2007/01/21/infopath-and-web-service-data-connection/)

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer, it's unfortunately not possible , and you can create a web service to connect your database and get the data based on the filter. please check the attached link to know how you can do that , Hope it helps you :)